# Routing inside routes - A setup function was called after the first request was handled

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to create routes inside of another route (`info_form()`). For awhile this was working. I am not sure what exactly caused it, but I may have changed some code and that is what caused it to stop working. This is my code:

```py
@app.route('/Register', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
        FormErrMessage = 'Email already taken, or invalid email.'
        error = False
        if request.method == 'POST':
                    inp_email = request.form['email']
                    inp_password = request.form['password']

                    if User.objects(email=inp_email):
                        error = True
                    else:
                        @app.route('/Register/customer-form', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
                        def info_form():
                                msg = None
                                if request.method == 'POST':
                                    form = request.form

                                    inp_name = form['name']
                                    inp_lastName = form['lastName']
                                    inp_zipCode = form['zipCode']
                                    inp_address = form['address']
                                    inp_phoneNumber = form['phoneNumber']

                                    if User.objects(name=inp_name, lastName=inp_lastName):
                                        msg = '...'
                                    elif User.objects(phoneNumber=inp_phoneNumber):
                                            msg = '...'
                                    else:
                                        @app.route('/Register/customer-form/verify/<send>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
                                        def verify_email(send):
                                                msg = None
                                                error_msg = None
                                                r = 8

                                                if send == 't':
                                                    ...

                                                if request.method == 'POST':
                                                    inp_code = request.form['code']

                                                    if int(inp_code) == r:
                                                        try:
                                                            User(
                                                                email=inp_email,
                                                                password=inp_password,
                                                                user_id=get_user_id(),
                                                                admin=False,
                                                                loggedIn=1,

                                                                # ip_addresses=ipAddress,
                                                                registered=False,
                                                                name=inp_name,
                                                                lastName=inp_lastName,
                                                                zipCode=inp_zipCode,
                                                                address=inp_address,
                                                                phoneNumber=inp_phoneNumber
                                                            ).save()

                                                            email(...)
                                                        except ValidationError as e:
                                                            print(e)
                                                            error_msg = '...'
                                                        else:
                                                            session['email'] = inp_email
                                                            session["password"] = inp_password
                                                            print(session)
                                                            return redirect('/')
                                                    else:
                                                        msg = 'Code invalid, try again.'

                                                return render_template('verify.html', email=inp_email, unk_err=error_msg,
                                                                       msg=msg)
                                        return redirect('/Register/customer-form/verify/t')
                                return render_template('customerform.html', msg=msg)
                        return redirect('/Register/customer-form')
        return render_template('register.html', FormErrMessage=FormErrMessage, error=error)
```

It seems to be raising this because the request was already handled.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\William\Nickels\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2463, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\William\Nickels\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2449, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\William\Nickels\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1866, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\William\Nickels\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\William\Nickels\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\William\Nickels\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\William\Nickels\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\William\Nickels\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\William\Nickels\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\William\Nickels\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\William\Nickels\app.py", line 55, in register
    @app.route('/Register/customer-form', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
  File "C:\Users\William\Nickels\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1314, in decorator
    self.add_url_rule(rule, endpoint, f, **options)
  File "C:\Users\William\Nickels\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 90, in wrapper_func
    "A setup function was called after the "
AssertionError: A setup function was called after the first request was handled.  This usually indicates a bug in the application where a module was not imported and decorators or other functionality was called too late.
To fix this make sure to import all your view modules, database models and everything related at a central place before the application starts serving requests.
```

Can someone tell me how to fix this or get around it. Thanks.
I don't understand this:

```
import all your view modules, database models and everything related at a central place before the application starts serving requests.
```

Comment: There is no reason or point to putting routes inside of other routes. That's probably where your problem is stemming from. Put the routes at the top levels, leave the logic of the if statement in this route, and just make calls to the other ones as needed by what the logic dictates. This is a mess and as you are finding out, a pain to maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What that error is trying to say is that you can't do setup-y things (like adding routes) after the Flask app has starting running.

You have a deeper problem, which is assuming that nested route functions will retain visibility an data from enclosing routes. E.g., that the `/Register/customer-form` route will have access to the `inf_email` set in the enclosing `/Register` route. The mechanisms here don't work that way.

Since the intent is to hang on to information from one step of a registration workflow to the next, the common mechanisms is to inject state from one route as hidden form elements so that they'll be carried along to the next route. Here, that would mean passing `inf_email` et al. to be expanded into the "customerform.html" template (and similar for the "verify.html" template).

Comment: @peter How do I pass template arguments from one route to another? Or do you expect me to use session or data stored in the url?

Comment: You inject them into form elements of type=HIDDEN. They'll be passed along to the next route when the form is submitted.